# Constraining images to edge of screen on Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, constraints

I have made a game with many objects on the screen which go from right to left, I have placed these items on my storyboard.

It's a single view application and the Title logo and play button aren't displaying how I would like them to on a 3.5" screen, so i am trying to make the app keep them a certain distance away from the screen edge, i have tried using constraints for this, but i am unable to constrain it to the screen edge rather than another item on the story board.

Since these other items on the story board are moving, it provides me with yellow errors that the content its aligned to is "ambiguous".

Any help would be much appreciated, should I try two story boards instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the view containing the `title logo` and the `play button` is not moving, then you may do this the following way:

Add a `Bottom space to superView` constraint, to your `play button` in storyboard.

**Steps:**

With the play button object as selected, Click on 
`Editor -> Pin - > Bottom Space to Superview`

[image]

Similar methods can be used with other objects too, such as adding constraint `Top Space to Superview` for `Title Logo`, so that the logo remains at a fixed position at the top.

For further doubts regarding `constraints` and `Autolayout`, you may refer these wonderful tutorials:

- [Beginning Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS 7: Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)
- [Beginning Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS 7: Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2)

**Update:**

If you get compiler warnings such as 

`"Frame for "Image View - Title.png" will be different at run time."`

It is because you have changed the frame of an item after adding the constraint.
If you want the new position:

`Editor -> Resolve Autolayout issues - > Update constraints`

If you want the original previous position:

`Editor -> Resolve Autolayout issues - > Update frames`

[image]

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hello GoGreen, thanks a lot for your response, but unfortunately i am still receiving the same errors! :S   -  it says "Frame for "Image View - Title.png" will be different at run time." and "Horizontal Position is ambiguous for "Image View - Title.png"."

Comment: This is because you haven't explicitly mentioned the horizontal position for the `Image View - Title.png`. Once, you set a constraint, its your Job to specify the exact position of the item at runtime. Try setting `Leading Space to Superview` constraint for that item as mentioned above.